# Transform a component into a hook that provide component and handers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'would like to expose the component, the state of the component within some handlers to interact with it, but I'm not aware of the caveats this might have, and never seen something like this. Can you provide some guide here?

Is a pattern a never saw, anyways, seems to be valid to me.

The hook:

```
const useEmptyCartModal: useEmptyCartModalHook = ( {
  testID,
  orderID,

} ) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const [ isEmptyCartModalOpen, setIsEmptyCartModalOpen ] = useState( false )
  const router = useRouter()
  const navigateToShop = () => router.push( ShopRoutes.getShopUrl() )
  const [ abandonOrder, { loading: abandonOrderLoading, error: abandonOrderError } ] = useAbandonOrderMutation()

  const handleOnCompleteEmptyCart = () => {
    setIsEmptyCartModalOpen( false )
    navigateToShop()
  }

  const handleEmptyCart = () => orderID && abandonOrder( {
    variables: { input: { orderID } },
    onCompleted: handleOnCompleteEmptyCart,
  } )

  const openEmptyCartModal = () => setIsEmptyCartModalOpen( true )

  const emptyCartModal = <EmptyCartModal
    isOpen={ isEmptyCartModalOpen }
    setOpen={ setIsEmptyCartModalOpen }
    submitting={ abandonOrderLoading }
    testID={ testID }
    onSubmitEmptyCart={ handleEmptyCart }
  />

  const emptyCartError = abandonOrderError ? t( ComponentsCartDetailsI18n.MESSAGES_EMPTY_CART_ERROR_TEXT ) : undefined

  return( {
    emptyCartModal,
    emptyCartError,
    openEmptyCartModal,
  } )
}


export { useEmptyCartModal as default }
```

In the component I would use the Component and the component that will interact with it:

```
const { openEmptyCartModal, emptyCartModal, emptyCartError } = useEmptyCartModal( {
    testID: getTestID( 'EmptyCartModal' ),
    orderID: cart.id,
  } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that doing this way is necessarily a problem, but I think that if your are dealing with a modal component is better to make an abstraction of the modal component and change the contents of it programmatically.

You can do this by creating a "global" component that acts like a modal recipient and use a State handler such as *redux* or *react contexts* to manipulate the contents and visibility of the modal box then you would be able to put anything in the modal recipient the `emptyCart` component and whatever else you need.

There is nothing wrong with the way you're doing it just doesn't scale well, but if you're not going to have a lot of different types of modal boxes than your solution is good enough.